# Overriding a destructor - C++

Tags: c++

Suppose I have:

```
struct Base
{
    /**/ virtual /**/ ~Base() {/*..*/}
    // ...
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    ~Derived() /* override */ {/*..*/}
    // ...
};
```

When a class inherits from another class, overriding is here to help me to make sure I'm implementing a function that actually exists in `Base`.
In this scenario described above, `Derived` class has a different name from `Base`, and therefore its destructor is written differently.

My question is, in case I want to use `override`, where shall I use that?
Where do I really implement a `Base`'s function in Derived class?

Comment: Note that `//Equal to =defualt` is not strictly true.

Comment: You can override `father`s functions in `son`, you can't implement `father`s functions in `son`.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: There's a bit of confustion. The "override" keyword simply means "some parent has this function as virtual". The destructor though is a special case: virtual destructors are always called (up the inheritance chain), regardless of implementation.

Comment: So what would happen if the Fathers destructor isn't virtual?
It would still go through the inheritance chain, which starts at Son and goes up to Father.
The problem would start while working with pointers and references of Father, which might be Son?

Comment: @maor36a sure, but only if you have `Son*`. But what happens when I have `Father* obj = new Son();` and I do `delete obj;`? The same "virtual logic" that applies to functions, applies to destructors as well.

Comment: note that the `father` - `son` analogy is a rather poor one for base and inherited class. public inheritance models a is-a relation and thats already where the analogy breaks down. "Every son is a father" doesnt really make sense. just saying, it took me years to overcome this wrong idea some stupid teacher injected into my brain

Comment: You probably could rewrite the question as: "How to ensure that base class destructor is `virtual`? I can check that, for regular methods, with `override`".

Comment: I edited/renamed Father/Son to Base/Derived.

Comment: To check whether `Base` has a virtual destructor, you can use `std::has_virtual_destructor` type trait. Possibly in combination with `static_assert` if you want to ensure instead of check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all "override" keyword simply means "this function is marked as virutal in some base class", nothing else. And it can be applied to destructors as well. Destructors however are special, normal rules don't apply to them. For example destructor in `Derived`, named `~Derived()` is matched with destructor in `Base`, named `~Base()`, even though formally they have different names (or do they? what is a name here anyway?).

Another difference between destructors and typical functions is that destructors are always called up the inheritance chain, regardless of implementation. And so you cannot "replace" destruction, you can only "extend" it. Note that (unlike normal functions) calling base class destructor from derived destructor is a mistake.

The chained destruction call starts at the class you are refering to at the moment. What I mean is

```cpp
Base* inst = new Derived();
delete inst;
```

will call `~Base()` because the variable `inst` is `Base*` even though it was constructed from a derived class. At this point "virtual logic" applies: if `~Base()` is not virtual then normal destruction procedure fires for `Base` class, without being aware that the actual object is `Derived*`, i.e. `~Base()` and all its parent desctuctors (there are none in this particular case) are executed. Which is wrong. But if it is virtual then it will actually jump to the correct class, `Derived`, and the correct destruction procedure is invoked: first `~Derived()`, then `~Base()`. [See this godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/iC1JkL) and play around: add and remove "virtual" in base destructor to see the difference (look at the left column only, lines with colored background are those that are actually called).

All in all: yes, you can use `~Derived() override {}`. I always use "override" where appropriate, it's nice to know which functions are derived from virtuals. Also the rule of thumb is: if `Base` is virtual (meaning any function is virtual) then its destructor should be virtual as well. Remember this well and it will help you avoid some problems.

Comment: *"if ~Base() is not virtual then it will start here and go up the inheritance chain. Which is wrong."* Are you sure it will go up the chain?

Comment: @wally well, things become more complicated when multiple inheritance is used. It's a simplification. Is that what you mean? Also note that in this particular case `Base` doesn't have parents so there's no place to go up of course. But I'm talking about general case.

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to understand is this; if we have a non-virtual destructor then it would only call the base destructor, right? There would be no implicit calls of other destructors along the chain.

Comment: But I don't see this happening. Non-virtual only calls a single destructor.

Comment: The part that says: *" if ~Base() is not virtual then it will start here and go up the inheritance chain."*

Comment: @freakish Well, it does not "go up the chain". How could it? A non-virtual member function call is statically resolved at **compile time,** simply considering the **static type** of the expression whose member function is called. In this case  `*inst` is a `Base`; it is statically determined and hard-wired that `Base::~Base()` will be called which knows nothing of `Derived`. You can actually see it in your godbolt example: Without `virtual` only two `delete`s are called: one for `*inst` and one for its `Base::data1`. The resource `Derived::data2` is leaking.

Comment: @freakish I See. Yes, a super class could be above, a base class could be below. I feel dizzy.

Comment: I've updated the answer and used different wording.

Comment: Are you explaining in this answer what would happen if `Base` had parents? I think this is what makes that part so confusing. Customarily, an example of `Base` would not ever imply having another parent.

Comment: @wally yes, that's what I've tried to do. I hope now the answer is clear.

Comment: Yes, much clearer now. Even the wally can understand.

Comment: if `~Base` is not `virtual`, `delete inst;` is simply UB.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, some of C++ linter tools (like clang-tidy) already have a checking mode that could complain that your derived class doesn't mark derived virtual destructor with "override" clause. So yes, despite the fact you're not obliged to do so (according to `12.4.9` chapter of C++ Standard), you could explicitly apply "override" to catch a situation once your base class is not virtual-destructible anymore but derived classes intend to still have that.

And, yeah, just do not worry about difference is destructor names (it is a syntax catch, not more) and thing of it as `void ~()` method.